# How to access a custom repository from a controller in doctrine 2.0 and Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Im unable to access a custom repository from a controller in doctrine 2.0 and Zend framework?

I have my file structure as following:-

```
application/controllers
       /configs
       /domain/
              Entities/User.php
                      /Mappings/User.php
              Proxies/
              Repositories/
vendor/
    Doctrine
```

In User.php, i have included like this:

```
namespace Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * @entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\UserRepository")
 * @Table(name="User")
 */
class User
{
}
```

Even i tried with

```
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * @entity(repositoryClass="Entities\UserRepository")
 * @Table(name="User")
 */
class User
{
}
```

Ive generated repositories to the domain/Repositories by the command.

Now i have my customized repositories in the folder domain/Repositories.
Ill want to access the ex: UserRepository in my UserController.php
I tried this.

```
$this->em = Zend_Registry::get('em');

$userlist = $this->em->getRepository('Repostories\User')->getusers();
```

Output: No such file or directory

If i tried:

```
$this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->getusers();
```

Output: getusers() function is missing. ur function should start by findBy

Please help in regards to this.

Thanks,
Hephzibah.

Answer (score 12):

Start with the repository

```
// Repositories/UserRepository.php
namespace Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getusers()
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Now the entity

```
// Entities/User.php

namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    // etc
}
```

Provided your autoloader can find classes in both `Repositories` and `Entities` namespaces, the following should work

```
$em->getRepository('Entities\User')->getusers();
```

Comment: Just a offtopic question, is not a bad practice to use the repositories inside my controllers, right?

Comment: @Jonathan Can't see why not. You could encapsulate the business logic in a service class or similar but that really depends on your design

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Phil that this is most likely an issue of autoloading - I ran into the same problem. It was solved by adding an _init function to the application bootstrap file with entries for my service, entity, and repository classes like below. You'll have to adjust yours to match your paths, obviously. My structure has Service, Entity, and Repository directories inside the default Zend Framework models directory.

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

    require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

    $serviceAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Service', APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($serviceAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Service');

    $entityAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entity', APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($entityAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Entity');

    $repositoryAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Repository', APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($repositoryAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Repository');

    return $autoloader;
}
```